# How can I configure an Active Directory authorisation provider for OAuth2?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

I've actually came accros Dave Syer's excellent Oauth2 exemple server found here : https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot and the reference documentation of spring-security-Oauth : http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html.

I understand the concepts of OAuth2 Authorization Server but I am actually looking to plug it on our Active Directory. Before using OAuth2, I used `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` without problem.

I can't find any implementation of `ClientDetailsService` that is pluggable to an Active Directory.

Did I miss something or do I have to write my own LDAP / AD implementation of `ClientDetailsService` ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm trying to do the same at the moment and stumbled across the same issue. What might work is to use JWT if this is an option for you cause the link back from your resource server to the oauth provider will not be necessary. The other option which I tried is to store the information read from the user after a successful authentication into a cache and retrieve it in the custom `ClientDetailService`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the heads up. I guess I'll try to write my own implementation until someone comes with a better idea. Meanwhile you would upvote my question so we can get more visility on the matter.

Many thanks !

Daniel

Comment: Sure! Sorry my bad! And good luck!